# Regex to ignore certain words before getting to another word

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a file with items lists in this order

```
List of items to stash (10 items):

                    dd98a4  41871
                    dd98a4  41872
                    dd98a4  41873
                    dd98a4  41874
                    dd98a4  41875
                    dd98a4  41876
                    dd98a4  41877
                    dd98a4  41878
                    dd98a4  41879
                    dd98a4  41880
```

I also have a lot of other lists that I have not included here within the same file. I would like to get a regular expression to use to check if item `"41879"` for example is in "List of items to stash". So pretty much to check if the string "List of items to stash <**ignore everything else in between**> dd98a4  41879". Is there a simple regex for this in ruby?

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want to check if that string "dd98a4 41879" is included in the file?

Comment: There are several other lists within the same file and "dd98a4 41879" or any other item can be in more than one list. I only want to check if it is in a specific list within the same file. Thats why I would need to use a regular expression starting with <Lists name> ignore everything else <item>

Comment: Where is the list name? What is dd984a (the list name?) and what is 41... (the item?)

So the format of the file is:

<LIST><WHITESPACE><ITEM><NEWLINE>
<LIST><WHITESPACE><ITEM>..
?

And an item is numeric whereas a list is hex?

Comment: Sorry for the formatting flaw. The list name is: List of items to stash (10 items): the item is <hex_id> <item_number>

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read "[ask]", including the links at the bottom, along with "[mcve]". We need to see evidence of your effort, either where you searched and why those pages didn't help, or the minimal code necessary to demonstrate the problem you're having, along with minimal input data and the expected output. Without that information it looks like you're hoping we'll do your research and write the code for you. While a regex can do what you want, it may not be the best way to accomplish what you want. How big are your files? Can your search targets repeat?

Comment: The log files are dealing with are not particularly colossal. The search items are very consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the format is:

`list1:
item1
item2
list2:
item1
item2
item3`

You are looking for  which is followed by anything but another  and your item:

`<NAME OF LIST>:[^:]*<ITEM>`

Replace  and  with your strings.

Test it here: http://rubular.com/r/H80Se07I1h

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we read the following from a file:

```
str = <<_

List of items to hide (3 items):

                    cc98a4  41878
                    cc98a4  41879
                    cc98a4  41880

List of items to stash (3 items):

                    dd98a4  41878
                    dd98a4  41879
                    dd98a4  41880

List of items to discard (3 items):

                    ee98a4  41878
                    ee98a4  41879
                    ee98a4  41880
_
```

and are given

```
list = "List of items to stash"
id = 41879
```

The following regex matches the descriptor that precedes the `id` in a line associated with the list `list`:

```
r = /^#{list}[^\n]*\n+(?:\s*\w+\s+\d+[^\n]*\n)*\s*\K\w+(?=\s+#{id})/
  #=> /^List of items to stash[^\n]*\n+(?:\s*\w+\s+\d+[^\n]*\n)*\s*\K\w+(?=\s+41879)/
```

Note how Ruby has replaced `list` and `id` with their values in the regex.

Sure enough:

```
str[r]
  #=> "dd98a4"
```

This regex probably looks somewhat complex. When you break it down into pieces, however, it's not so bad:

```
^          # match beginning of a line
#{list}    # match the value of list
[^\n]*\n+  # match the rest of the line followed by all blank lines (if any)
(?:\s*\w+\s+\d+[^\n]*\n)* # match, in a non-capture group, >= 0 spaces, one
           # word, > 0 spaces, > 0 digits, the rest of the line, repeatedly 
           # matching the non-capture group >= 0 times
\s*        # match >= 0 spaces at beginning of next line
\K         # forget everything matched so far
\w+        # match a word (what we want)
(?=\s+#{id})/ # in a positive lookahead, match > 0 spaces followed by the id
```

Comment: Very insightful, thanks. Would +1 if I was able to. I'm new to Stack Overflow